# Cordova Sencha Touch Blackberry App java.lang.illegalArgumentException

Tags: blackberry, cordova, sencha-touch

I have developed a sencha touch app that runs fine on all supported phones when opened up from a web site.

When I build the app as a native phonegap app using cordova 1.5 and 1.6 the app again runs on android phones (haven't tried iphone) and in the ripple emulator. However, when I load the app in the Blackberry Webworks emulator, or onto a blackberry phone I get a java.lang.illegalArgumentException.

I have even stripped the app to little more than a hello world example, but I still get the same error.

I have managed to get the sample cordova app running on a blackberry, so I knnow the phone is not the problem.

Any help with this problem would be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ridiculous amount of trial and error it turns out that error was being caused by the png file I was using for my splash screen. Seemingly the splash screen image must be less than 16 kb